# How to access resource files from java dynamic web application

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services

I have started to create a java webservice after following this [tutorial](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BottomUpAxis2WebService/bu_tutorial.html). I made the web service more complex by making it to access a resource file under projectfolder/res/file.txt. Now the problem is when I access the service from a client programs, the webservice give a FileNotFoundException. I have tried putting the file.txt int to WebContent folder also, but it didn't work. what do u guys think?

Comment: how are you getting the file in your code?

Comment: I tried File file = new File("path"); but it's not working (FileNotFound Exception) that's what I want to get solved.

Comment: try to put file in src folder then locate the file using `File file = new File("test.txt");` check, is this working ?

Answer (score 1):

Solution #1:
Give the full path of the file in the File constructor. Please note this can cause portability issues. Eg. File f = new File("C:\programs\proj\WEB-INF\test.txt");

Solution #2:
Use getResourceAsStream() method to read the file as described in the following thread,
[getResourceAsStream() vs FileInputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308188/getresourceasstream-vs-fileinputstream/2308203#2308203)